# Coleta de informações em massa de arquivos

Tags: bash, shell-script

Pretendo coletar ctime, atime, mtime e crtime de uma massa considerável de arquivos.

Como solução parcial montei o seguinte scritp:

```
sudo debugfs -R 'stat <1055890>' /dev/sda1|awk -F': ' -v c='' -v a="" -v m="" 'BENGIN {} $1==" ctime" {c=$2} $1==" atime" {a=$2} $1==" mtime" {m=$2} $1=="crtime" {print c, a, m, $2}'
```

> debugfs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
>   0x5ade9510:c7eb0e9c -- Mon Apr 23 23:23:12 2018 0x5b05601f:111ab67c -- Wed May 23 09:35:43 2018 0x5ade9510:c7eb0e9c --
>   Mon Apr 23 23:23:12 2018 0x5ade9510:c7eb0e9c -- Mon Apr 23 23:23:12
>   2018

Pretendo capturar as informações da seguinte forma:

Mon Apr 23 23:23:12 2018, Wed May 23 09:35:43 2018, Mon Apr 23 23:23:12 2018, Mon Apr 23 23:23:12 2018

Onde serão respectivamente ctime, atime, mtime e crtime em um futuro csv.

Como posso tratar as variaveis para pegar somente após " -- "?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar um script `awk` para resolver o seu problema (`script.awk`):

```
BEGIN {
    OFS = ",";
    FS = " -- ";

    print "ctime,atime,mtime,crtime"
}
{
    for( i = 0; i < 4; i++ ){
        split( $(i+2), a, " 0x" );
        b[i] = a[1];
     }

     print b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3];
} 
END {
}
```

Uso:

```
debugfs -R 'stat <1055890>' /dev/sda1 | awk -f script.awk > saida.csv
```

Tudo em uma linha:

```
debugfs -R 'stat <1055890>' /dev/sda1 | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=",";FS=" -- ";print "ctime,atime,mtime,crtime"}{for(i=0;i<4;i++){split($(i+2),a," 0x");b[i]=a[1]};print b[0],b[1],b[2],b[3];}' > saida.csv
```

Saída (`saida.csv`):

```
ctime, atime, mtime, crtime
Mon Apr 23 23:23:12 2018,Wed May 23 09:35:43 2018,Mon Apr 23 23:23:12 2018,Mon Apr 23 23:23:12 2018
```

Answer (score 1):

Resumindo minha resposta, o comando completo ficaria:

```
sudo debugfs -R 'stat <1055890>' /dev/sda1 | 
awk -F'--' '{gsub(/0x[a-z0-9:]+/, ""); print $2, $3, $4, $5}' | 
sed -r 's/^ //;s/  +/, /g'
```

---

***Resposta completa:***

Com `awk` não é estritamente necessário atribuir variáveis arbitrárias, uma vez que os valores posicionais já servem ao seu propósito de possibilitar o retorno só daquilo que você quer.

Assim, definindo o separador de campos como a string "--", através da flag `-F`, é só dar um `print` nos campos desejados. No exemplo abaixo executei um `gsub` para também remover os valores hexadecimais:

```
[stat...] | awk -F'--' '{gsub(/0x[a-z0-9:]+/, ""); print $2, $3, $4, $5}'

> Mon Apr 23 23:23:12 2018    Wed May 23 09:35:43 2018    Mon Apr 23 23:23:12 2018    Mon Apr 23 23:23:12 2018
```

Por fim, para eliminar espaços indesejados e adicionar as virgulas entre campos, um `sed` rápido:

```
sed -r 's/^ //;s/  +/, /g'
```

O comando completo, de acordo com a pergunta, ficaria:

```
sudo debugfs -R 'stat <1055890>' /dev/sda1 | 
awk -F'--' '{gsub(/0x[a-z0-9:]+/, ""); print $2, $3, $4, $5}' | 
sed -r 's/^ //;s/  +/, /g'
```

> Mon Apr 23 23:23:12 2018, Wed May 23 09:35:43 2018, Mon Apr 23 23:23:12 2018, Mon Apr 23 23:23:12 2018

---

Para fins de desempenho, caso pretenda executar o `stat` de muitos arquivos, sugiro guardar o resultado completo de todas as execuções de stat em um só arquivo e depois executar esse `awk | sed` uma só vez, passando o arquivo de stats como entrada para o `awk`:

```
awk -F'--' '{gsub(/0x[a-z0-9:]+/, ""); print $2, $3, $4, $5}' arquivo-de-stats | 
sed -r 's/^ //;s/  +/, /g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando o *awk*, você pode definir como delimitador o conjunto "-- ".

Um script simples utilizando seu comando como exemplo ficaria:

```
#!/bin/bash

var=$(sudo debugfs -R 'stat <1055890>' /dev/sda1|awk -F': ' -v c='' -v a="" -v m="" 'BENGIN {} $1==" ctime" {c=$2} $1==" atime" {a=$2} $1==" mtime" {m=$2} $1=="crtime" {print c, a, m, $2}')

ctime=$(echo $var | awk -F"-- " '{print $2}'| rev | cut -d" " -f3-7 | rev)
atime=$(echo $var | awk -F"-- " '{print $3}'| rev | cut -d" " -f3-7 | rev)
mtime=$(echo $var | awk -F"-- " '{print $4}'| rev | cut -d" " -f3-7 | rev)
crtime=($echo $var | awk -F"-- " '{print $5}')
echo "$ctime", "$atime", "$mtime", "$crtime"
```

> Mon Apr 23 23:23:12 2018, Mon Apr 23 23:23:12 2018, Mon Apr 23
>   23:23:12 2018, Mon Apr 23 23:23:12 2018

Explicação:

No awk, a flag *-F* indica o delimitador que será usado, e o print indica a coluna que será exibida.
Como o resultado desse parse traz um conjunto de caracteres não desejados, foi necessário utilizar o cut em conjunto com o rev para remover a última coluna e manter apenas a data.
Obs.: Para o *crtime*, como não existe a última coluna, podemos dispensar o cut no filtro.

Se for rodar o comando muitas vezes, recomendo encapsular a solução abaixo em uma função:

```
function parse_date {
  ctime=$(echo $1 | awk -F"-- " '{print $2}'| rev | cut -d" " -f3-7 | rev)
  atime=$(echo $1 | awk -F"-- " '{print $3}'| rev | cut -d" " -f3-7 | rev)
  mtime=$(echo $1 | awk -F"-- " '{print $4}'| rev | cut -d" " -f3-7 | rev)
  crtime=$(echo $var | awk -F"-- " '{print $5}')

  echo "$ctime", "$atime", "$mtime", "$crtime"
}
```

Depois você chamaria a função passando o resultado do seu comando como argumento:

```
parse_date "$var"
```

> Mon Apr 23 23:23:12 2018, Mon Apr 23 23:23:12 2018, Mon Apr 23
>   23:23:12 2018, Mon Apr 23 23:23:12 2018